# How to send cloudwatch custom metrics to Amazon Quicksight Dashboard

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-quicksight

I am publishing custom metric data (count of how many times operations are being used by customers) to cloudwatch. I want to use these custom metric data to be shown on Amazon Quicksight dashboard ; do anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same, so I wondered if you made any progress with this?

Comment: Wondering the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Athena to read the Cloud watch metrics as seen in AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-prebuilt-data-connectors-cwmetrics.html.
Then you can connect Quicksight with Athena as data source https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-data-set-athena.html or utilize S3 where data resides now.